# SBT: How to publish both the aggregate project and all modules on Sonatype?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a SBT project which I was publishing to Sonatype with no issue and I converted it to a multi-module SBT project. Now I want to:

- publish the jar/javadoc/sources/pom file containing all the aggregated submodules to Sonatype
  (meaning that they should be signed with the sbt-pgp plugin)
- publish each individual submodule to Sonatype as well

I tried to use the [sbt assembly plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) for this but didn't manage to get very far. Do you have a sample Build.scala file which would show what is the best structure to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this project in question available on github if I want to test my theory?

Comment: Do you mean like we do in lift? We have the framework aggregate project which I do publish and sends everything, and you can also go into individual sub projects

Comment: @EugeneYokota: yes it is for specs2: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/tree/specs2-modules. But I don't want to give you work that I should be doing myself.

Comment: @fmpwizard yes if you publish the sub projects as well. I'll have a look at lift's own configuration, thanks.

Comment: Then yes, there isn't really a framework jar, it is only the aggregate. And then subprojects like lift-json , lift-util end up on sonatype, with their own docs, source, etc

Comment: @Eric It wasn't too much work, plus I owe specs2 man-months anyways. The meta question – Why do you need to publish an aggregate jar instead of keeping it broken down?

Comment: I want to ease the transition for people having the "big" dependency. When they are ready they can change for smaller jars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible with currently available plugins, but using [ScopeFilter](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#getting-values-from-multiple-scopes), you might be able to create an artificial project that aggregates all sources, from there it's just the matter of calling `publishSigned` in there.

See how I aggregate source in [sbt-unidoc](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-unidoc).

Here's the proof of concept: https://github.com/eed3si9n/specs2/commit/18f6405c91cf995f621a84c65e05d66407ba4964

With the change I was able to run `package`, `doc` etc. You might have to aggregate `*.class` if you use macros.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your pull request, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I use the sbt assembly plugin for Casbah - https://github.com/mongodb/casbah

Casbah has a top level aggregate project but I also package a single all dependencies jar by adding an extra artifact to the build:

```
addArtifact(Artifact("casbah-alldep", "pom", "jar"), assembly),
```

See the build file for more info: https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/project/CasbahBuild.scala